# Strange Behavior for the predict() function

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, cart-analysis

I am currently taking the "Practical Machine Learning" course from Coursera right now and am having run across some strange behavior with the predict function.  The question that has been asked was to train a tree and then make some predictions.  So that I am not posting the answer here I have changed the dataset used for the problem.  The code is as follows:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(rattle)
data(mtcars)
mtcars$vs = as.factor(mtcars$vs)
set.seed(125)
model = train(am ~ ., method = 'rpart', data = mtcars)
print(model)
fancyRpartPlot(model$finalModel)

sampleData = mtcars[1,]
sampleData[1,names(sampleData)] = rep(NA, length(names(sampleData)))
sampleData[1, c('wt')] = c(4)
predict(model, sampleData[1,], verbose = TRUE)
```

In the above code, there are two primary sections.  The first builds the tree and the second (where `sampleData` starts) creates a small sample set of data to apply the model to.  To make sure that I have the exact same structure as the original data I simply copy the first row of the training dataset and then set all the columns to `NA`.  I then put data in only the columns that the decision tree needs (in this case the `wt` variable).

When I execute the above code, I get the following result:

```
Number of training samples: 32 
Number of test samples:     0 

rpart : 0 unknown predictions were added

numeric(0)
```

For reference, the following is the structure of the tree:

```
fancyRpartPlot(model$finalModel)
```

[image]

Can somebody help me to understand why the `predict` function is not returning a predicted value for the `sampleData` that I provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, even though `rpart` only used the `wt` variable in splits, prediction still requires the others to be present. Use a data set with the sample columns:

```
> predict(model, mtcars[1,])
[1] 0.8571429
```

Max

Comment: I have accepted your comment because it is most likely correct. Thanks for the reply.  It is nice to know that I am not simply doing it wrong.


That being said, I think that this behavior is not expected and should be updated in the rpart package...  Possibly I should bring that up with the package managers.